# Error - The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysobjects', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the error message

```
Error - The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysobjects', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

when I try to upgrade an EPiServer-site.
The upgrade is using user and password stored in a connection string for the site.

What changes should I do in Sql Server Management Studio for this user in order to get select permission (and possibly the other permissions that will needed to perform the upgrade) for the object 'sysobjects'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You execute this non-query: `GRANT SELECT ON sys.sysobjects TO you;` where `you` being the username. You can only do this as the admin(usually user `sa`)